# How would I .click this button?

Tags: javascript, click, tampermonkey

I'm trying to press this button, this is the information from the inspect

```
<form action="?p=casino" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="game" value="6">
    <input type="submit" value="Play" class="button">
</form>
```

In other button presses I could simply do

```
var missionButton = document.getElementById(CrimeID); //CrimeID is the ButtonID from the /crimes page/ variables at the top of this script.
missionButton.click();
```

CrimeID is "Form1" so I was able to just select form1 and .click  but I'm not able to do that with this one because there isn't a form id or anything and it's specific to the value (I need it to be 6) that's shown in the snippit.

Comment: Please provide more code, and explanation about what you try to achieve

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to select the `<input type="hidden" name="game" value="6">` tag in JavaScript (is that what you want, right?).

If you want to use vanilla (ie pure) JavaScript, without JQuery, you can do:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].getAttribute('name') === 'game' && inputs[i].getAttribute('value') === '6') {
        var buttonYouWant = inputs[i];
    }
}

buttonYouWant.click();
```

However, I would advise you to use JQuery if you can, because the implementation is far easier. Please check https://jquery.com/ for more.

Comment: var input = document.querySelector('input[name="game"]') is faster. And no need for jQuery. At all

Comment: Not in the case he needs to make sure that the value is 6. And also querySelector is not compatible with all browsers as you can see in http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector (that's why I suggested jQuery)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for some reason, it doesn't do anything, I turned it into a function and called it but nothing happens. also with tampermonkey atleast the .click has to be inside the loop so i put it under the var... any idea?

Comment: Have you debugged to see if the problem is with the selector or with the click() method? If not, try adding ```console.log(buttonYouWant);``` right after the ```var buttonYouWant ...``` to make sure the right object is being selected.

Comment: So it does find the correct button , the problem is it doesn't click.

Comment: Ok. So, are you sure there is some event listener added to the event "click" in this hidden input? If you want to submit the form what you should do is actually select the "submit" input rather than the hidden one.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense, I still need the specific number'd one to submit though, I looked over the code and assumed maybe i can just copy it to a new variable but it doesn't seem that easy since every "play" button is setup like that other then the specific # variable associated with it, How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Ok so you need to submit only the form that has an input named game with the value = 6 right?

Comment: Yes Arthur     zzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: Try ```buttonYouWant.nextSibling.click();``` instead of ```buttonYouWant.click();``` (notice that the next node should be the submit input for this to work)

Comment: http://puu.sh/pjmoD/01768895b4.png -Console from
`
function Dothing(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        if(inputs[i].getAttribute('name') === 'game' && inputs[i].getAttribute('value') === '6') {
            var FirstInput = inputs[i];
            console.log(FirstInput);
            var Submit = FirstInput.nextSibling();
            console.log(Submit);
        }
    }
}




Dothing();
`

Comment: Shouldn't it be next sibling with the form itself?

Comment: ALSO I ADDED 
            Submit.click();
Doesn't work still because the .nextSibling won't work.

Comment: What happens when you ```console.log(Submit);``` ?

Comment: It can't get to that point because .nextSibling doesn't work as a function apparently for tampermonkey maybe? so it can't equal nothing.

Comment: Oh got it. So try ```var submit = varFirstInput.parentElement.querySelector('input[type=submit]');``` (notice: querySelector is not yet compatible with all browsers in usage so you may want to change this code if selling or distributing to other users)

Comment: Not distributing or selling so it's perfect Thank you, added a 
`setInterval(function(){Dothing();}, 250);         // Starts Play button clicking intervals`

it doesn't work without the function(){} though it just spams it all at once i've never understood why, or its just not loading ... but it's working now so thanks!